# Avoid postback on OnClick event of View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have two views as below :

Index.cshtml

```
    <p>
       @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Owner ", new { id = "lnkCreate" })
    </p>

 @section JavaScript {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Owner.js")"></script>

    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
 <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Owner", new { id = "lnkBack" })
        </div>

@section JavaScript {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Owner.js")"></script>

}
```

Script >> Owner.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {


   $('#lnkBack').click(function (e) {                  // not working
        alert('hello')
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Owner/Index',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#divContent').hide();
                //$('#divGrid').html(data);
            }
        });

    });

    $('#lnkCreate').click(function (e) {                 //working fine

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Owner/Create',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
               // $('#divGrid').hide();
               // $('#divContent').html(data);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

What I want to accomplish that whenever i click on "Create New" link it is working as coded without any postback. But when i click on "Back" link of the different view under same controller it is doing postback and not going to click event as in written in script code.

Comment: Create the action links with empty hrefs.

Comment: Not the issue, but I suggest you inspect the html that your generating = your using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: @Sippy thanks .. can you please provide me in details what you are saying.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have already inspected the html rendered but it is showing the correct id which i had set for Back link.. I hope I am getting you right.

Comment: Yes its adding the `id` attribute, but look at the `href` attribute - its probably ends with something like `/...?length=6` (as I said its not the issue because you recreate the url in the script)

Comment: Wasn't suggesting that my idea would fix it, just that putting a href in is a bit pointless imo.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you want me to see the url of page after clicking on back link or on inspecting the back link. In both cases there is no appended url as length= 6.

Comment: @Sippy even after putting empty href its doing postback on click.

Comment: Stephen wants you to append necessary information to your question. I already said that what I said isn't going to fix your issue.

Comment: @vivek, Again, its not the issue, but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) is the overload list for `Html.ActionLink()` - there is no overload that accepts 3 strings and a dictionary - the closest match is `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)`. Just wanted to make you ware of it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 function bindClicks(){
   $('#lnkBack').click(function (e) {                  
        // alert('hello')
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Owner/Index',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#divContent').hide();
                //$('#divGrid').html(data);
                bindClicks();
            }
        });

    });

    $('#lnkCreate').click(function (e) {                 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Owner/Create',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
               // $('#divGrid').hide();
               // $('#divContent').html(data);
               bindClicks();
            }
        });

    });
 }

bindClicks();

});
```

Basically you need to rebind the click() functionality after fetching content via ajax.

The jQuery functions that run when your page is loaded is agnostic of any new content that is added via ajax. You have to run the same functions again every time new content is added on your page (if this content has some jQuery functionality such as click bindings). A good place to do that is the ajax "success" (the new content is fully added to the page)